# How to set the read and write rules for a specific user in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In my app I'm using Firebase authentication, and I also have an entry in the Firebase Realtime Database where I store other user information, like, full name, age, gender, etc. What I want to do is to connect the authenticated user to its user information in Firebase Realtime Database, and, in the rules, to only allow the user to read and write to his own user information in the Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you a database schema that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- $userId
              |
              --- fullName: "John"
              |
              --- age: 22
              |
              --- gender: "male"
```

To grant read/write access to the owner of the user account whose UID exactly matches the key ($userId), please use the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of a question somewhere ? seems too simple to not have been asked before?

Comment: @a_local_nobody maybe this is first developer who didn't check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#the_auth_variable) where described **exactly** this case

Comment: @a_local_nobody It may be. If you find the duplicate one, please mark this question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: i was just asking because usually there are quite nice Q&A posts for firebase related questions, i just thought this would fall under that, but maybe it doesn't